# Network does not automatically resolve the containers

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: 'bitnami/redis:latest'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
  companyclassifier:
    depends_on:
      - redis
    image: abc:latest
```

I am trying to access redis via my application but it does not automatically resolve no matter what I try. I finally managed to connect to my redis container by executing:
docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -aqf "name=redis_1")
After going inside the container I managed to use redis-cli -h and the ip address. Is there any way to get this ip address either automatically resolved or get it during runtime?

Comment: Any reason they are not on the same network? redis will be on the default network created by docker-compose, and companyclassifier is on the host network. They need one network in common

Comment: Originally it was without that, but then I cannot connect even with the ip address